# Evolution has no access to couchdb

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, evolution, contacts, couchdb

Evolution gives the error "Cannot open addressbook". "We were unable to open this addressbook.  This either means you have entered an incorrect URI, or the server is unreachable". "Details: Operation not permitted". (rough translation from Dutch).

Enabling verbose logging in (desktop)couchdb tells me roughly the same:

```
[info] [<0.7875.1>] 127.0.0.1 - - 'PUT' /contacts/ 400
[debug] [<0.7875.1>] httpd 400 error response:
 {"error":"invalid_consumer","reason":"Invalid consumer (key or signature method)."}
```

It *seems* that evolution tries to fetch the contacts, then couchdb denies access, and then evolution fails to do a proper oauth.

This is on Ubuntu 10.10, with its default dektopcouch 1.0.1.

Any hints on where to start would be most appreciated :)

Comment: Could you tell me what version of Ubuntu (and of desktopcouch) you're on?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 and couchdb 1.0.1, comes default with 10.10. Will add to the question too.

Comment: The guy who can best answer this is on holiday today; I'll push him this way tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried a lot of things already, but describing all my attempts will only clutter the question. So please ask me anything you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there Desktopcouch entries in gnome-keyring (System / Preferences / Passwords and Encryption Keys or `seahorse`)?
If no then you may be hitting bug [LP:668409](https://bugs.launchpad.net/desktopcouch/+bug/668409).

Comment: I have three keyrings (two being imports from a backup). All three had -indeed- desktopcouch entries. I removed all of them, restarted couchdb and  they did not re-appear. Expected result "2 new entries for DesktopCouch auth" not met.  Workarond in LP:668409 works for me and fixes my problem!

Answer (score 3):

it would be better if you could get debugging output from Evolution itself. So, please, quit evolution and then, on a terminal:

```
killall -9 e-addressbook-factory
/usr/lib/evolution/e-addressbook-factory
```

then start Evolution as usual (from the menu) and try to connect to your Ubuntu One addressbook. When it fails, go back to the terminal and paste all output you see there into your question.

Comment: About the same problem ** (e-addressbook-factory:16595): WARNING **: Could not get OAuth tokens from keyring: No matching results

** (e-addressbook-factory:16595): WARNING **: Could not create DesktopcouchSession object