# Stop and start desktop couch with "service"?

Tags: 10.10, couchdb, desktopcouch

I think I'm hitting the same error as [Evolution has no access to couchdb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21986/evolution-has-no-access-to-couchdb) but the first step in the solution is to "stop desktopcouch service"

`Service` doesn't know desktopcouch (or couch, as far as I can tell). `ps` shows a number of couch instances running. I could just kill them all by process ID, but that seems like a hack.

```
amanda    4290  0.0  0.0   1896   592 ?        S    10:16   0:00 /bin/sh -e /usr/bin/couchdb -n -a /etc/couchdb/default.ini -a /etc/xdg/desktop-couch/compulsory-auth.ini
-a /home/amanda/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini
-b -r 0 -p /home/amanda/.cache/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.pid
-o /home/amanda/.cache/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.stdout
-e /home/amanda/.cache/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.stderr
-R amanda    4314  0.0  0.0   1896   304 ?        S    10:16   0:00 /bin/sh
-e /usr/bin/couchdb -n -a /etc/couchdb/default.ini -a /etc/xdg/desktop-couch/compulsory-auth.ini
-a /home/amanda/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini
-b -r 0 -p /home/amanda/.cache/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.pid
-o /home/amanda/.cache/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.stdout
-e /home/amanda/.cache/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.stderr
-R amanda    4315  3.0  0.6  81816 19376 ?        Sl   10:16   1:55 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.7.4/bin/beam.smp
-Bd -K true -A 4 -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /home/amanda -- -noshell -noinput
-sasl errlog_type error -couch_ini /etc/couchdb/default.ini /etc/xdg/desktop-couch/compulsory-auth.ini /home/amanda/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini
-s couch -pidfile /home/amanda/.cache/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.pid
-heart amanda    4334  0.0  0.1  20448  3552 ?        Ssl  10:17   0:00 /usr/lib/couchdb/bin/couchjs /usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js amanda    4519  0.1  0.4  19216 12568 ?        S    10:29   0:05 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-service amanda    4548  0.2  0.4  19824 12356 ?        SN   10:29   0:07 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-service amanda    5841  0.0  0.0   4012   756 pts/3    S+   11:19   0:00 grep couch
```

What's the right way to start and stop desktopcouch in 10.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems what I wanted was `/usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-service` and/or `/usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-stop`

Answer (score 1):

The `service` utility is used to control system wide services, while `desktopcouch` is a per-user service.

There isn't currently a defined command to kill `desktopcouch`, but `killall desktopcouch-service` should do the trick.  The service should be started automatically next time it is used.