# Xubuntu 19.10 High temperature

Tags: xubuntu, 19.10, fan, temperature

I'm running Xubuntu 19.10 on my laptop (Lenovo Legion Y540), it seems to be getting pretty hot (screenshot added), and the fans are running like hell.

I have a dual boot with Windows. I checked the temps there and those are a few degrees lower, and the fans are quieter.

Any idea what can I do?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's certainly warm but not sure I would call that "hot".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T61 Lenovo Laptop overheats - is there a fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70920/t61-lenovo-laptop-overheats-is-there-a-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to change few setting, once I've configured Nvidia X server settings to run on the Intel GPU (and not on Nvidias), the fans seems to be getting quiet, and temps went down.