# How can I radically mimimize power usage when I need to conserve battery?

Tags: power-management, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop minimal power consumption tweaks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67965/laptop-minimal-power-consumption-tweaks)

I often work from locations where I don't have a way to plug in my laptop and I need to get some single thing done. I'm looking for some good strategies that I could use to shut off all the processes I don't need (local Apache server, mysql and postgres) when I know I won't have a way to plug in for a while, but restore them when I do have power and would prefer to have my full development environment available.

How do other people manage this? Do background database servers use enough power for this to be worth doing?

I've got a Thinkpad x301, running 11.10. If that makes any difference.

Here's what powertop says is using power now:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 11.5 W

Summary: 1113.1 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/second and 0.0 VFS ops/sec

            Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
         4988 rpm                   Device         Laptop fan
         50.9 ms/s     267.3        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/firefox http://t.co/xxxx
          3.6 ms/s     228.3        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
        106.0 ms/s      87.8        Process        /opt/TweetDeck/bin/TweetDeck
         22.6 ms/s     110.2        Process        /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -backgrou
          7.8 ms/s      74.1        Process        /usr/bin/gtk-gnash -u http://a.vimeocdn.com/p/flash/moogalover/1.1.19/moogalover.swf
          7.6 ms/s      59.5        Process        /usr/bin/gtk-gnash -u http://service.twistage.com/plugins/player.swf -U http://servi
          0.9 ms/s      47.8        Interrupt      PS/2 Touchpad / Keyboard / Mouse
          3.3 ms/s      17.6        Process        /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-service
          7.2 ms/s      13.7        Process        compiz
          0.8 ms/s      14.6        Interrupt      [6] tasklet(softirq)
          1.0 ms/s      13.7        Interrupt      [44] i915
        431.9 µs/s      10.7        Process        postgres: writer process
          1.2 ms/s       9.8        Timer          tick_sched_timer
        670.7 µs/s       9.8        Process        nautilus -n
        182.9 µs/s       9.8        kWork          ieee80211_iface_work
```

I can see a few things to kill (Tweetdeck and the firefox tabs with Flash in them), [Desktopcouch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47857/stop-and-start-desktop-couch-with-service), [UbuntuOne](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123678/how-can-i-do-to-stop-ubuntuone-syncd), but those GTKGnash processes don't disappear when I stop Firefox.