# Can't open Evolution CouchDB address book

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, evolution, desktopcouch

> Unable to open address book
>
> This address book cannot be opened. 
>   This either means that an incorrect
>   URI was entered, or the server is
>   unreachable.

I tried the solution (and suggestions) in [Evolution has no access to couchdb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21986/evolution-has-no-access-to-couchdb) but that isn't working for me.

I tried stopping desktopcouch-service and deleting my access keys and now the error I get says

```
Unable to open address book

This address book cannot be opened.  This either means that an incorrect URI was entered, or the server is unreachable.

Detailed error message: Address Book does not exist
```

Do I need to create my addressbook anew?

Comment: Trying these instructions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyArentMyContactsInEvolutionSyncing

Comment: Those had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved several weeks after this post (It is mentioned in the link you provided). My recommendation is:

1. Update 10.10
2. Upgrade to a new release

This is since the link mentioned by you did not work (Does not work for some people)