# Can't create CouchDB addressbooks in evolution?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, evolution, couchdb

I can't seem to create new couchDB addressbooks in evolution or [open the ones Evolution thinks I have.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47880/cant-open-evolution-couchdb-address-book). I've tried walking through [these suggestions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyArentMyContactsInEvolutionSyncing) to no avail:

```
$ killall beam.smp beam
beam: no process found
$ rm /home/amanda/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini 
$ dbus-send --session --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB --print-reply --type=method_call / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPort
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

The next suggestion is to `killall -9 e-addressbook-factory` then `export COUCHDB_DEBUG_MESSAGES=1` and relaunch with `/usr/lib/evolution/e-addressbook-factory&`

e-addressbook-factory isn't running, but relaunching it looks to go fine. When I try to view my CouchDB address books (I tried creating a second one, so I have two now), I get this:

```
** (e-addressbook-factory:6491): WARNING **: Couldn't get port for desktopcouch: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/service.py", line 702, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-service", line 73, in getPort
    port = int(desktopcouch._direct_access_find_port())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/desktopcouch/__init__.py", line 193, in __find_port__linux
    return __find_port__linux(pid, ctx, retries_left - 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/desktopcouch/__init__.py", line 193, in __find_port__linux
    return __find_port__linux(pid, ctx, retries_left - 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/desktopcouch/__init__.py", line 193, in __find_port__linux
    return __find_port__linux(pid, ctx, retries_left - 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/desktopcouch/__init__.py", line 194, in __find_port__linux
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find listening port")
RuntimeError: Unable to find listening port


** (e-addressbook-factory:6491): WARNING **: Could not create DesktopcouchSession object
```

The last suggestion there -- stop desktopcouch and remove the .ini file and cached  couchdb.html  -- doesn't work any better.

```
** (e-addressbook-factory:6680): WARNING **: Couldn't get port for desktopcouch: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

** (e-addressbook-factory:6680): WARNING **: Could not create DesktopcouchSession object
```

I actually don't need my data, I've got that. I would like to start using UbuntuOne's contact sync, however. There's clearly something missing here.

Comment: Not sure why I put this in an answer intially, but the update to 11.04 didn't change anything.

Comment: In 11.10 I am able to add new CouchDB calendars in Evolution but since UbuntuOne has disabled phone syncing of contacts there's really not much point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you Rm your desktop.ini file.

When you restarted couch it may have not re-installed the file successfully.
I had this problem for a while.

Try /usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-service

dbus-send --session --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB --print-reply --type=method_call / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPort

xdg-open file:///home/amanda/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html

This will recreate the ini files, randomize the ports and reboot the system completely.
Once this is done it will show you your details on the Apache server

Comment: Thanks for this - I ran desktopcouch-service manually and found that the permissions for some of the log files were wrong and it was quitting. Deleted the log files and it's happy now.

Comment: In 11.10 I can open and create CouchDB addressbooks in Evolution, so I can't test @Christopher Stansbury's fix. Accepting his answer b/c it helped Nick.